# LM324 comparator IC getting burnt

Tags: heat, comparator

[image][image]I am using LM324N as a comparator which has Reference voltage of 1.2V to +ve terminal. It requires supply voltage VCC=24V & VEE=Gnd.When input is 0V Vout=24 and when input= above reference voltage Vout=24v.

The problem is that

IC is getting over heated and burning at VCC and Gnd pin.

Comment: What is connected to Vout? According to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm324) the max output current is +- 60mA, are you within that range?

Comment: opto coupler and from opto coupler to PLC

Comment: So you have the optodiode connected to 24v (opamp output) with just 100 Ohm resistance? That would require a current of more than 200mA which is outside the operating range of the opamp and is probably too much for the optodiode too

Comment: Hi pls find the full circuit added..

Comment: In this schematic, why does each component have multiple reference designators like (R1, R11, R21, R31) etc. Are you duplicating the circuit in your board with all the 4 comparators in LM324?

Comment: What voltage and ripple do you measure on that "+24V" supply? What we can see of the schematic suggests it's unregulated...

Comment: What am I missing here? I don't see why the comparator is needed at all. Just connect the optocoupler LED and its resistor in parallel with R1. Are we actually trying to measure the resistance of the contactor?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using a 24VAC/3A transformer, which will give you a DC voltage of \$ \sqrt 2\ \cdot 24\$ VDC plus whatever regulation the transformer allows under light load, plus maybe some line voltage tolerance.

That could easily be 40V or 42V, which exceeds the 32V absolute maximum supply voltage of the [LM324 quad op-amp](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm224.pdf) by a considerable margin (as Brian Drummond has hinted at).

[image]

Comment: It might be an 18VAC secondary the OP uses - lose 1.4V in the bridge and you get just short of 24V DC

Comment: @Andyaka  Yup, it *might* be. But my bet is on the 24V/3A. They're a lot more commonly available. The only other easy way to fry a '324 is to reverse the supply voltage (easy since the pins locations are a bit odd) but there's no sign he's doing that.

Comment: its 18VAC secondary.. whats solution for this?

Comment: Ha, well my guess was wrong. Mea culpa. You have not done something like grounding the unused _outputs_ , have you? No offense intended, but there are some very strange things about that schematic (like two 35V capacitors in _series_ to give half the value).

Comment: i am using all the outputs . And one more i am using same supply for two Isolation module,In that one isolation module does not have problem (LM324 not getting heat).Another one IC getting heat.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, what are the possible reasons for IC get over heat?

Comment: Reverse supply. Too high supply voltage or too much voltage between inputs (maybe transient). Too much current drawn from output. Voltage below GND to an input. Bad chip from previous damage. That's about it.